# How to compare two array objects(very nested) and if exists return the match value

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I was trying to compare two arrays, because I want to return the match value(if found), which is this case is an id, so I was trying:

```
var found = this.imgGallery.filter(o1 => !this.articles.some(o2 => o1.id === o2.id));
```

AND

```
  var found = this.imgGallery.find( val => this.articles.includes(val) )
```

Where this.articles and this.imgGallery is just the name of the getters. I always get the find and filter is not a function, I was reading and found out that is related to the fact they are not arrays but objects. What is the correct way to do this? This is a example structure(I have severals registers) I have for the 2 objects:

Array 1

```
{
    "data": {
      "allGalleries": [
        {
          "titleGallery": "",
          "yearGallery": {
            "year": "2020",
            "id": "49620624"
          },
          "tags": [],
          "submitImages": [
            {
              "id": "21120705"
              
              },
              {
              "id": "21120718"
                  
              }
          ],
          "descriptionGallery": "Sample Description",
          "id": "51181471",
          "event": {
            "id": "49621565",
            "categoryName": "Sample Category"
          }
        },
        {
          "titleGallery": "Title",
          "yearGallery": {
            "year": "2020",
            "id": "49620624"
          },
          "tags": [
            {
              "id": "50947050",
              "tag": "tag 1"
            }
          ],
          "submitImages": [
  
            {
              "id": "21118615",
              "url": "https://website.com/53092/1628238076-0129.jpg",
              "notes": "Title"
   
            },
            {
              "id": "21118614",
              "url": "https://website.com/53092/1628238067-0128.jpg",
              "notes": "Sample Notes"
            },
            {
              "id": "21118613",
              "url": "https://website.com/53092/1628238059-0127.jpg",
              "notes": "Sample Notes"
  
            },
            {
              "id": "21118612",
              "url": "https://website.com/53092/1628238051-0126.jpg",
              "notes": "Sample Notes"
            }
           
      ]
    }
  }
```

Array 2

```
{
    "data": {
      "allArticles": [
        {
          "id": "51325400",
          "articleTag": [
            {
              "tag": "tag 1"
            },
            {
              "tag": "tag 2"
            },
            {
              "tag": "tag 3"
            }
          ],
          "articleTitle": "Title",
          "categories": {
            "categoryName": "Category"
          },
          "articleContent": "Sample content",
          "articleDate": "2020-09-19T00:00:00+02:00",
          "year": {
            "year": "2020"
          },
          "imageUrl": {
            "url": "https://www.website/53092/1628439919-m203861fine.jpg"
          },
          "addGalleryEvent": {
            "id": "51325401"
          },
          "addVideoGallery": null
        },
        {
          "id": "51324383",
          "articleTag": [
            {
              "tag": "Tag 1"
            },
            {
              "tag": "Tag 2"
            },
            {
              "tag": "Tag 3"
            }
          ],
          "articleTitle": "Sample title",
          "categories": {
            "categoryName": "category name"
          },
          "articleContent": "Sample Content",
          "articleDate": "2020-09-15T00:00:00+02:00",
          "year": {
            "year": "2020"
          },
          "imageUrl": {
            "url": "https://www.website/53092/1628423323-20200916daz1529.jpg"
          },
          "addGalleryEvent": {
            "id": "51324387"
          },
          "addVideoGallery": null
        }
        
      ]
    }
  }
```

******** UPDATE: *************
Just in case: to be more precise, I need to check is an id inside submitImages (articles) match with an id inside of addGalleryEvent(galleries), and I don't have the id value, that's why I need to check if a match is found and return it.

Comment: Can you post your data as text instead of a screenshot?

Comment: @Wimanicesir sorry, it's updated now : )

Comment: Anyhow, if your comparing two object just use: Obj1.data.id === Obj2.data.id

Comment: Can you also explain what data should be checked with what? The two objects contain different data

Comment: To be more precise, I need to check is an id inside submitImages (articles) match with an id inside of addGalleryEvent(galleries), and I don't have the id value, that's why I need to check if a match is found and return it

Answer (score 0):

Based off your description, I wrote this. However this doesn't result in a found match. Is this the code you were looking for?

```js
var articles = {
    "data": {
      "allArticles": [
        {
          "id": "51325400",
          "articleTag": [
            {
              "tag": "tag 1"
            },
            {
              "tag": "tag 2"
            },
            {
              "tag": "tag 3"
            }
          ],
          "articleTitle": "Title",
          "categories": {
            "categoryName": "Category"
          },
          "articleContent": "Sample content",
          "articleDate": "2020-09-19T00:00:00+02:00",
          "year": {
            "year": "2020"
          },
          "imageUrl": {
            "url": "https://www.website/53092/1628439919-m203861fine.jpg"
          },
          "addGalleryEvent": {
            "id": "51325401"
          },
          "addVideoGallery": null
        },
        {
          "id": "51324383",
          "articleTag": [
            {
              "tag": "Tag 1"
            },
            {
              "tag": "Tag 2"
            },
            {
              "tag": "Tag 3"
            }
          ],
          "articleTitle": "Sample title",
          "categories": {
            "categoryName": "category name"
          },
          "articleContent": "Sample Content",
          "articleDate": "2020-09-15T00:00:00+02:00",
          "year": {
            "year": "2020"
          },
          "imageUrl": {
            "url": "https://www.website/53092/1628423323-20200916daz1529.jpg"
          },
          "addGalleryEvent": {
            "id": "51324387"
          },
          "addVideoGallery": null
        }
        
      ]
    }
  };
  
 var galleries =
   {
    "data": {
      "allGalleries": [
        {
          "titleGallery": "",
          "yearGallery": {
            "year": "2020",
            "id": "49620624"
          },
          "tags": [],
          "submitImages": [
            {
              "id": "21120705"
              
              },
              {
              "id": "21120718"
                  
              }
          ],
          "descriptionGallery": "Sample Description",
          "id": "51181471",
          "event": {
            "id": "49621565",
            "categoryName": "Sample Category"
          }
        },
        {
          "titleGallery": "Title",
          "yearGallery": {
            "year": "2020",
            "id": "49620624"
          },
          "tags": [
            {
              "id": "50947050",
              "tag": "tag 1"
            }
          ],
          "submitImages": [
  
            {
              "id": "21118615",
              "url": "https://website.com/53092/1628238076-0129.jpg",
              "notes": "Title"
   
            },
            {
              "id": "21118614",
              "url": "https://website.com/53092/1628238067-0128.jpg",
              "notes": "Sample Notes"
            },
            {
              "id": "21118613",
              "url": "https://website.com/53092/1628238059-0127.jpg",
              "notes": "Sample Notes"
  
            },
            {
              "id": "21118612",
              "url": "https://website.com/53092/1628238051-0126.jpg",
              "notes": "Sample Notes"
            }
           
      ]
    }
  ]}
 }
 var matches = []
 var idToCheck = 0
// First get the id we need to search for
articles.data.allArticles.forEach(a => {
  idToCheck = a.addGalleryEvent.id
  console.log('Id to check: ', idToCheck)
  // Loop all galleries
  galleries.data.allGalleries.forEach(gallery => {
    // Loop all images of that gallery
    gallery.submitImages.forEach(image => {
      // If the image id is the same, we add it to the matches
      if (image.id === idToCheck) {
        matches.push(image)
      }
    })
  })
})

// Log the result
console.log(matches)
```

Comment: Hello @Wimanicesir thank you very much for take time into this : ). Unfortunately this won't work because this is just checking the first position inside allArticles at the begining, the array up is an example of the structure but I have hundreds of registers like those inside galleries and articles,  and as mentioned before, I don't know the value of id. The reason why I am trying to do it like this," if a match is found" for me means, that that article register have a gallery, and also can get the id if I return the match to display the correct gallery under the article.

Comment: If you want a list of all matching objects, you could adjust the code so it loops all allArticles to get the current idToCheck and the rest will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understood from your question, you want to return a boolean whenever an object inside submitImages has an id that matches with an id in any of the articles.

If that's the case, then this should work:

```js
let result = false
for (let i in arr1.data.allGalleries) {
    let gal = arr1.data.allGalleries[i]
  let filtered = arr2.data.allArticles.filter(a => gal.submitImages.some(i => i.id === a.addGalleryEvent.id))
  if (filtered[0]) {
    result = true
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Darken, thank you for your time, I'm not a expecting a boolean, however based on your function  if I return "filtered" I should be having what I need, however again when running this I get the "filter is not a function error"

Comment: Hello @druj_nasu I noticed something that might be the error. When testing the function, I noticed the allGalleries array is broken, as it lacks an ending square bracket and an ending curly bracket, which might be the problem.

Comment: Hello DarkenLM, no worries, this is just an example structure, those objects are coming from a graph API, I just copied and pasted part of the generate query for illustration purpose.